# How can I match namespace prefixes with regular expression

Tags: regex, xml, namespaces, prefix

What I really want to do is to match all namespace prefixes both for tags and attributes by using a regular expression.

For example:

```
<foo:person bar:id="43">
  text text <nomatch:free text
  <baz:name>
    text nomatch:free> text
  </baz:name>
    text nomatch:free="44" text
    <age bae:years="44" />
    text
</foo:person>
```

What I want is to extract only the following prefixes: foo, baz, bad, bae, bar

I cannot find a regular expression for implementing this.

Please take account that the regular expression should not have hardcoded the names foo, baz, bad, bae, bar...

Comment: use a xml parser. xml is not regular language

Comment: The sample text given in the question isn't XML (due to the unescaped `<`) so in this case an XML parser won't work.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Something like this?</strike>

```
[<]([^:]+)
```

will put the prefix (after the angle bracket and before the colon) into group 1.

I see that I misinterpreted the question, after looking more closely.

```
[<](((\w+):\w+)(\s+(\w+):\w+="\d+"\s*[\/])?)>
```

which will have a result in groups $3 and possibly $5.  I think this will do it.

Whoops, missed a ?

```
 [<](((\w+):\w+)(\s+(\w+):\w+="\d+"\s*[\/]?)?)>
```

Comment: Oh sorry, just realised you wanted the parametres as well.

Comment: Unfortunately this regular expression does not work.. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
x='<foo:person bar:id="43">'
y=re.findall(r"(\w+)(?=:)",x)
print y
['foo', 'bar']
```

This is in python.Hope this solves ur problem.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a perl version:

```
my @collects = $str =~ /[<|\s](\w+):[^free]/ig;
```

Comment: Oh common now, that's cheating :)

Comment: @mclaassen He didn't say to not use values, just not hard coded names.  :P   Any case, here's an improved version:                                    `my @collects = $str =~  /<(\w+):\w+(?:\s(\w+):\w+=.+)?>/g;`

Comment: Unfortunately this regular expression does not work.. :(